# How do I extract everything from the start of a line to a specific string?

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed, grep

I've been working on this for days and can't seem to figure it out, I hope someone can help.  I'd prefer an answer that can be run in the linux command line, like grep, sed, awk, etc.

Say I have a file named "file.txt" with the contents:

```
1234jpg.jpg a.jpgbjpgy.jpg uyapss.jpg>"sdf
5678jpg.jpga.jpgbjpgy.jpg uyapss.jpg>"sdf
ABC not this line
```

What I want to do is extract everything up to ".jpg" that would give me the result of:

```
1234jpg.jpg
5678jpg.jpg
```

Some commands I've tried (among hundreds of other variations) are:

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/\(^.*\.jpg\)/\1/'

cat file.txt | sed -e 's/^[^"jpg"]\(.*\.jpg\)/\1/'

cat file.txt | egrep '^([^jpg]*[jpg])'

cat file.txt | grep -Po '\(\K.*jpg\)'

cat file.txt | grep -Po '(?<=\.jpg).*'
```

I'd love any help with this.

Sean

Comment: You could also use `grep`.  Say `grep -Po '.*?\.jpg' file.txt`

Comment: This command didn't work.  It makes everything after .jpg to be on a new line which gives me 8 .jpg file names, not the 2 .jpg file names that are at the beginning of the line to the first match of .jpg.

Comment: I didn't realize that the anchor in the command was missing.  It should have been `grep -Po '^.*?\.jpg' file.txt`

Comment: Absolutely perfect!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F"[.]jpg" 'NF>1{print $1".jpg"}' file
1234jpg.jpg
5678jpg.jpg
```

We split the lines using `.jpg` as field separator. We select only those lines which has more than one such files and print the first element. We print the extension so that the output comes back as your desired output.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I wanted, thank you!  I could post well over 2000 commands I've attempted to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(\.jpg\).*/\1/' file
```

or:

```
sed -r 's/(\.jpg).*/\1/' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/\.jpg.*/.jpg/' file
```

Comment: All of these commands work if I redirect the output to filter out only lines with .jpg. 

sed 's/\(\.jpg\).*/\1/' file | grep "\.jpg"

Thank you!